# Filter Objects having the same property from two Lists and Update them and Store it in a 3rd List in Java 8

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, java-stream

I have the following class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public static class Manipulate {
    private int id;
    private int quantity;
}
```

And I have two lists `a` and `b`.

```
List<Manipulate> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(new Manipulate(1,100));
a.add(new Manipulate(2,200));

List<Manipulate> b = new ArrayList<>();
b.add(new Manipulate(1,10));
b.add(new Manipulate(2,20));
```

I need to filter these two lists based on the `id` property.

And I want to subtract quantities of objects contained in `b` from quantities of objects contained in `a` and store the result into a `List`.

*My attempt:*

```
List<Manipulate> c = a.stream().map(k -> {
    b.stream().filter(j -> j.getId() == k.getId())
        .forEach(i -> {
            int i1 = k.getQuantity() - i.getQuantity();
            k.setQuantity(i1);
        });
    return k;
});
```

I'm getting the following compilation error:

```
Required type: List <Manipulate> Provided: Stream<Object>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Stream<R> conforms to List<Manipulate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- `map()` is an *intermediate operation*, it means that it doesn't produce the resulting value but returns another stream. In order to produce a result from the stream you need to apply a *terminal operation* (e.g. `collect()`, `reduce()`, `findFirst()`). For more information, refer to the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).
- In *Functional programming*, it's not a good practice to mutate arguments passed to a *function* (and that's what you're doing inside the `map()`).
- Your code is based on a [*brute-force logic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) (which always imply the **worst** possible performance): for every element in `a` iterate over the all elements in `b`. Instead, we can index all the `id` that are present in the list `b` by placing them into a *hash-based* collection (that would allow to find out whether a particular `id` is present in the `b` in constant time) and associate each `id` with the corresponding `quantity`. I.e. we can generate `HashMap`, that maps each `id` in the `b` to it's `quantity`.
- Lists `a` and `c` would be identical because they would contain the same references. That means there's **no** point in generating the list `c` unless you want it to contain **only** elements having `id` that are present in the list `b`.

That's how your code might be reimplemented:

```
List<Manipulate> a = // initializing list a
List<Manipulate> b = // initializing list b

// mapping each `id` in the `b` to it's `quantity`

Map<Integer, Integer> quantityById = b.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Manipulate::getId,      // keyMapper
        Manipulate::getQuantity // valueMapper
    ));

// generating the list `c`, containing only elements
// with `id` that are present in the `b`
        
List<Manipulate> c = a.stream()
    .filter(m -> quantityById.containsKey(m.getId()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or .toList() for Java 16+

// updating `quantity` property of each element in `c`
    
for (Manipulate m : c)
    m.setQuantity(
        m.getQuantity() - quantityById.get(m.getId())
    );
```

In case if you had no intention to change the data in `a`, then you need to create new instances of `Manipulate` for every matching `id`. And it's perfectly fine to do in the stream:

```
List<Manipulate> a = // initializing list a
List<Manipulate> b = // initializing list b
Map<Integer, Integer> quantityById = // generate a map like shown above

List<Manipulate> c = a.stream()
    .filter(m -> quantityById.containsKey(m.getId()))
    .map(m -> new Manipulate(m.getId(), m.getQuantity() - quantityById.get(m.getId())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or .toList() for Java 16+
```

***Note:*** you need to add the third argument to `Collectors.toMap()` in case if there could be duplicated `id` in the list `b`.